# Is there a way to to generate a surefire report for the wro4j jshint maven plugin?

Tags: maven, jshint, wro4j

Is there a way to get the (excellent) wro4j jshint plugin to produce a surefire report as part of its execution?

I'm not sure if this is an outstanding feature request or if there is already a way of doing it.  Currently the only output I can get is command line - is that correct or have I missed anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not supported yet by default. There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=257) for that which will be fixed in one of the future releases. Until then, you can create a custom implementation of [JsHintMojo](https://github.com/alexo/wro4j/blob/v1.4.9/wro4j-maven-plugin/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/maven/plugin/JsHintMojo.java) and implement the surefire report support.

Comment: Thanks for that - if I get time I may look at trying to do this!

Comment: The xml reporting for csslint & jslint feature is already available in  development branch (1.4.x) and will be released as part of version 1.4.10

Comment: Brilliant - I'll take a look at that